# Rails 'rake db:seed' not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Upon trying to complete a 'rake db:reset' command, i am getting this error

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: missing required :bucket option
```

I've checked the several other posts here about this problem, but can't seem to find anything that works. This is all local hosting as of now so i don't think i need to do anything with Heroku.

In the seeds.rb file that the error points to, i have nothing even containing the word bucket, and in my development.rb file, my paperclip defaults are as follows:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => ENV['XXX_DEV_S3_BUCKET'],
  :url => ENV['XXX_DEV_S3_URL'],
  :access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
}
}
```

I've tried moving the bucket line out of the s3 credentials, but i get the same error. any help is appreciated.

edit: here is the area in my seed file where the error points, the entire file is pretty large

```
family = Family.create!({name: "family1"})

random = male_names.shuffle.pop.split
dad_first_name = random[0]
mom_first_name = female_names.shuffle.pop.split[0]
last_name = random[1]

parents = family.users.create!([
  {
      first_name: dad_first_name,
      last_name: last_name,
      username: 'parent1',
      email: dad_first_name + "@" + last_name + ".com",
      password: '123456',
      password_confirmation: '123456',
      role: "parent",
      avatar: File.open("#{Rails.root}/db/images/parent1.jpg")
  },
  {
    first_name: mom_first_name,
    last_name: last_name,
    username: 'parent2',
    email: mom_first_name + "@" + last_name + ".com",
    password: '123456',
    password_confirmation: '123456',
    role: "parent",
    avatar: File.open("#{Rails.root}/db/images/parent2.jpg")
  }
])
```

The error points specifically to the line that starts with "parents"

Comment: paste your seed file

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['XXX_DEV_S3_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  },
 :url => ENV['XXX_DEV_S3_URL'],
 :path => "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
})
```

Comment: my apologies, i didnt notice the changed first line. This gives me a new error with the same location 'TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String'

Answer (score 0):

The S3 bucket is configured to use `ENV['XXX_DEV_S3_BUCKET']`.

I would guess that you don't have that environment variable set.

Check the project for a file named `.env` or `.env.development` or `application.yml`.

These files are used by [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) or [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to manage environment variables.

If this is a Heroku application, you may also need to check `heroku config` to see if there are values set there.

Otherwise, you may need to pass them in yourself using one of the above tools to help, or pass them directly into the command-line like this:

```
XXX_DEV_S3_BUCKET=xxx-production S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID=1823123412 S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=blahblahblah bin/rake db:seed
```

Comment: hmm where would i find that file? i've been looking around but can't seem to locate anything like that

Comment: @LukeMeyer DotEnv is usually in the project root (since it starts with a dot, you might have to `ls -al` to see it). Figaro uses config/application.yml